# Referencing a PCL library with Roslyn results in .NET version issues

Tags: c#, .net, portable-class-library, roslyn

I'm trying to use Roslyn to execute a block of code that references a PCL library. Both my console application and the PCL library are targeted to .NET 4.5

The syntax tree executes a method in the referenced library that constructs a library class. There should be no .NET 4.0 references.

**(5,27): error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.**

Has anyone had issues with PCL and Roslyn, or got it to work before?

MyCompanyApplication:Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Emit;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace MyCompanyApplication
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      EmitResult Result;
      var Options = new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary);

      CSharpCompilation Compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(
          assemblyName: Path.GetRandomFileName(),
          syntaxTrees: new[] { CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(
@"class Test
{
  public void Run(MyCompanyLibrary.Class Class)
  {
    var Label = Class.NewLabel();
  }
}") },
          references: new[] 
          {
            MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location),
            MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(MyCompanyLibrary.Class).Assembly.Location),
          },
          options: Options);

      Assembly Assembly = null;
      using (var Stream = new MemoryStream())
      {
        Result = Compilation.Emit(Stream);

        if (Result.Success)
          Assembly = Assembly.Load(Stream.GetBuffer());
      }

      if (Result.Success)
      {
        var TestType = Assembly.GetType("Test");
        var Instance = TestType.GetConstructor(new Type[0]).Invoke(new object[0]);
        var RunMethod = TestType.GetMethod("Run");

        RunMethod.Invoke(Instance, new object[] { new MyCompanyLibrary.Class() });
      }
      else
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Test (PCL) failed");
        Console.ReadLine();
      }
    }
  }
}

class Test
{
  public void Run(MyCompanyLibrary.Class Class)
  {
    var Label = Class.NewLabel();
  }
}
```

MyCompanyLibrary:Class.cs

```
namespace MyCompanyLibrary
{
  public class Class
  {
    public Class()
    {
    }

    public Label NewLabel()
    {
      return new Label(this);
    }
  }

  public class Label
  {
    internal Label(Class Class)
    {
      this.Class = Class;
    }

    private Class Class;
  }
}
```

[image: Solution References]

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015
Version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.00079

Comment: Never, *never* use an assembly from the GAC as a reference assembly.  They need to come from c:\program files (x86)\reference assemblies.  Specially crafted to hide the differences between the various 4.x versions.  Afaik you'll have to hard-code the path and hope that the machine has the correct targeting pack installed.  Using a PCL library is something you really don't like here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding a reference to `object` from your "MyCompanyApplication", which is not a portable class library.

Change this:

```
MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location)
```

to this:

```
MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Runtime.dll")
```